# java.lang.outofmemoryerror with firebase update

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a java `spring` application to parse a `file` about 220 Mb size  having 800 000 records. Purpose of the code is to push records into firebase database.
The problem I am facing is

> java.lang.outofmemoryerror gc overhead limit exceeded

This code will run fine for the first one or two times but subsequent calls will get slower and leads to out of memory error. This code snippet will work fine without firebase db update call. It has been observed the firebase db update call is not releasing the heap space even after it completes the execution.

```
fireDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getApps().get(0)).getReference(getEnvironment().getProperty(catalog_root_node));
BeanReader reader = getBeanReader("C:\\Users\\aneesh\\Desktop\\Feeds\\N01.S2.SWC.MGS2410.BAS.ATG");
CatalogDTO catalog = null;
int count = 0;
int clubNo = 0;
String clubItemRoot = "";
int currentSize = 0;
Map<String, Object> itemjason =  new HashMap<String, Object>();
int batchsize= Integer.parseInt(getEnvironment().getProperty(catalog_batch_size)) * Integer.parseInt(getEnvironment().getProperty(catalog_record_size));

while((catalog = (CatalogDTO) reader.read()) != null){
    if(null==itemjason){
        itemjason =  new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    if(!getFeedValidateManger().getFeedValidator(catalog_feed_type).isValidFeed(catalog)){
        logger.info("Catalog : Invalid Feed record format : "+ Integer.parseInt(catFeedArray[3]));
        continue;
    }
    clubNo = Integer.parseInt(catalog.getClubNo());
    clubItemRoot= clubNo+getEnvironment().getProperty(items_root_node)+catalog.getItemNo();
    getItemJsonPopertiesMap(itemjason,catalog,clubItemRoot);
    currentSize = itemjason.size();
    if(itemjason!=null && !itemjason.isEmpty() && currentSize>=batchsize)
    {
        fireDBRef.updateChildrenAsync(itemjason);
    }
    System.out.println(count++);
}
if(null!=itemjason && itemjason.size()<batchsize && itemjason.size()>0)
{
    firebaseService.updateFeedsToFirebase(fireDBRef, itemjason);
    itemjason = null;
}
logger.info(lineNum + " lines of catalog feeds written");
updateTracker(FeedInfoStatus.SUCCESS, "Sent records: " + getSuccessCount());
sendNotification();

} 
catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
    String msg = e.getMessage();
    updateTracker(FeedInfoStatus.FAILED, msg.length() >= MSG_MAX_LENGTH ? msg.substring(0, MSG_MAX_LENGTH - 1)
                       : msg);
    sendNotification();
}finally{
    fireDBRef = null;
    System.gc();
}
}
```

Comment: I'm just saying this based on the exception alone: are you closing/freeing up resources properly when you're done with them? Also  calling the garbage collector yourself usually is bad design.

Comment: @Neijwiert The issue is with firebase operation( without that this code works fine). Using JConsole I can see the heap space is still used after it finishes the execution. Is there any way through which I can forcefully release the heap memory

Answer (score 0):

You initialise itemjson to a new HashMap before the while loop but you never clear it until after the loop (unless this is done in one of the called methods but I don't get that impression) meaning it will continue to grow for each time through the loop.

Furthermore, you call updateChildrenAsync with itemjson in the loop when the size is > batchsize which will always be true after it is true the first time. So if batchsize is 100 you will call updateChildrenAsync once itemjason reached that size and then call it again once every time through the loop with mostly the same data.

Emptying itemjason directly after calling updateChildrenAsync should fix the problem.